# Convergence at a point implies convergence in a neighbourhood

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

Is the following statement true?

If a sequence $\{f_n\} \subset \mathcal{C}^0[a,b]$ of increasing functions converges at a point $x \in [a,b]$, then there is an open neighbourhood $U$ containing $x$ such that $f_n$ converges point-wise on $U$.

Comment: Either you didn't think enough before asking this: $f(x)=(2+(-1)^n) x$ is a counterexample with $x=0$... or you didn't state the question correctly. Is it about a sequence of increasing functions, or an increasing sequence of functions?

Comment: Increasing functions. Thank you for resolving this.